# Repeat Function w/ Second Argument?

Tags: javascript, repeat

I am a new coder making my way through Eloquent Javascript.  This is my first post.  I don't understand how the 'i' below is passed into the repeat function.  I did a console.log to see that it runs through 0-4.  How the 'i' automatically set at 0?  And then incremented up 1?

```
let labels = [];

repeat(5, i => {
    labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});

console.log(labels);
// → ["Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", "Unit 5"]
```

Thanks

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: repeat is not defined`. Please show the `repeat` function

Comment: `i` is a parameter to a callback function, which is set in a loop from 0 to n (n being 5 in your example), check the code here: https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#p_cNB+u+7TGa

Comment: I thing you are confused with `=>` in js. `i => {//do something}` is equivalent to function(i){//do something}. Take a look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Correct, I was confused and missed the callback function above the code I was looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the results, i assume, the `repeat` function is:

```
function repeat (times, func) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; ++ i) {
    func(i + 1);    // kindly note this line, as per your doubt
  }
}
```

So, `repeat` calls the function the given number of times, and as per your argument is, here:

```
func = i => {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}
```

therefore, `func` here is your passed function, it loops from 0 to 4 and `number + 1` is passed to `func` as parameter, so it gets looped from 1 to 5.

according to your question, you probably are confused why it is looping from `1..5` and not `0..4`, it is because of the line `func(i + 1);`

also note, as per @MTK comment:

```
i => {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}
```

and

```
function (i) {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}
```

are equivalent, (excluding the concept of context binding, `this`).

i hope it helped :)

Comment: This helped a ton, thank you.  I was able to wrap up that chapter in the book.  I am amazed at how much support there is here.  I hope I can return the favor someday.

Answer (score 0):

You've just considered the second part of the whole function here. Understand that in the book "Eloquent JavaScript", the author wrote the whole function as two separate functions presented below. The first part, set i=0, therefore i will start at zero(0). In the second part, I mean in the repeat function, n=5. Therefore i will be i<5 as written in the for loop. Meaning i will increment from 0 to 4.
Hope this clarifies everything that was confusing you.

```js
function repeat(n, action) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      action(i);
    }
  }

  let labels = [];
  repeat(5, i => {
    labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
  });
  console.log(labels);
```

Comment: You're really thinking that it is a worthy answer in comparing with accepted answer?

Comment: @AksenP I do not want in any way challenge anybody. I'm not challenging you either. I don't believe Stack Overflow asked contributors not comments or to stop commenting once an answer has been accepted. Your answer is the best and you got it. If mine can help anybody just a little bit, hey "God Thank You!".